# IIS 7 : Add PHP Code Automatically to Every Page

Tags: iis, iis-7

In IIS 7, is there any way for me to add a snippet of PHP Code to every page delivered, without having to add it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to add a snippet of PHP Code to every page delivered.